# Setting write permissions for temporary storage provided by Azure (Linux-based VM)

Tags: azure

Apart from using it for swap space, I'm going to be using the temporary storage available in my Azure VM (Ubuntu 14.04 OS) for storing Postgresql temporary files as well.

To enable that, I've to create a symlink at `/$PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp` that points to `/mnt/pgsql_tmp`. So that should be **`ln -s /mnt/pgsql_tmp $PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp`**.

This reasonably ensures all temp files are stored and read from the SSD-based temporary storage. However, one hitch: the user `postgres` does NOT have permissions to write to `/mnt`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4.0K Mar 18 12:40 mnt
```

How do I ensure `postgres` also has write permission on `/mnt`? Should I just do `sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt` and be done with it?

I know this is elementary, but since it's a production server and I've already got swap set up in `/mnt` I don't want to misconfigure it and run into problems tomorrow.

---

p.s. this is how the temporary storage currently looks like:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       221G  9.9G  200G   5% /mnt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ln -sTf /mnt/pgsql_tmp $PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp  # did you get that correct?
chown -R postgres              /mnt/pgsql_tmp
chmod o+x    /mnt          # note: no -R,  this turns 750 to 751 for /mnt only
```

The effect:

```
 su - postgres
 echo 1 > /mnt/file   # fails
 ls   /mnt            # fails
 cat /mnt/anything    # fails
 echo 1 >  /mnt/pgsql_tmp/file   # works
 ls /mnt/pgsql_tmp               # works
 cat /mnt/pgsql_tmp/file         # works
```

The `chmod o+x` means to give [o]thers the +e[x]ecute bit, which gives them a permission to traverse across `/mnt` into any subdirectory. Other permissions are not necessary for `/mnt` only for `/mnt/pgsql_tmp`

Comment: After >10 years of doing this, it still seems counterintuitive. I try to remember the order is the same for `ln` as for `cp`

Comment: Quick clarification: before doing this in production, I was trying it out locally on test folders. I created `/mnt` and `/pgsql_tmp` on my desktop, and then tried `ln -sTf /home/hassan/Desktop/mnt/pgsql_tmp /home/hassan/Desktop/pgsql_tmp`. This ends up giving me `ln: ‘/home/hassan/Desktop/pgsql_tmp’: cannot overwrite directory`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't create /mnt/pgsql_tmp as a directory. If it's a directory, it cannot be a symlink at the same time. If it's a symlink, it can be a symlink either to a file, a directory, or to another symlink.

Comment: Uhuh, guess I have it the other way around. I was thinking I'd delete the directory where pgsql temporary files are created, i.e. `pgsql_tmp` inside `$PGDATA/base/`, then create the directory `pgsql_tmp` inside `/mnt`, and then finally do `ln -sf /mnt/pgsql_tmp $PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp`

Comment: Use `ln -sTf` instead of `ln -sf`, it's important in your case. The rest seems very much correct.

Answer (score 3):

In order to allow user `postgres` to write to a folder, it would be preferred to make him be the `owner` of the folder instead of giving read-write access to everyone.

If `/mnt` should be used only by `postgres` then you should make `postgres` the owner of `/mnt` folder and all its sub-folders

```
sudo chown -R /mnt postgres
```

You might want to do this only for a sub-folder of `/mnt` e.g. to `/mnt/pgsql_tmp`

```
sudo chown -R /mnt/pgsql_tmp postgres
```

Comment: So wouldn't that curtail `root` from writing to `/mnt`?

Comment: `root` has full read/write access to any folder owned by any user

Comment: Yep, just wanted to be sure since this is production, 5-times more stressful than making changes in development :-)